# Dialog filtered menu

Tags: shell-script, dialog

I am currently making a script to manage themes in ArchLinux, basically it save arborescence of config files in a folder named with a prefix "gt-" for global-theme. All themes are saved in at $GT_DIR

I'd like to use dialog to show available themes, do a directory menu may be adapted, but I'd like to filter the content of dialog to show only "gt-" prefixed directories.

At first I thought of catching the list with a find and pass it to dialog, but I am not sure of how I can do this (if I can).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The directory-selection in [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) does not support filtering.  But you could construct a list showing some hierarchy with the `treeview` widget added at the [end of 2012](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/CHANGES.html#t20121230):

[image]

There are a few samples in the source code.

Comment: Where is the source ? So can I pass it an array of choices (with the standard --menu option) ?

Comment: dialog's source-code is found on the homepage, which is linked in the answer.  The `--treeview` is a different *widget* than the `--menu` option (similar, but different).  To populate it, you need the levels for each item in the tree.  Reading the examples would be helpful.